# Get message from other window

Tags: c, windows, winapi, message

I try to get some messages from other windows. I need to find window by name, I used  `FindWindowW()`. How can I get active window and get message from its?
When I add `hwnd` in GetMessage(), it doesn't work.

```
//WndProc
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            OutputDebugStringW(L"Key down");

            break;

//main.c
        //WNDCLASSEX wc;
        HWND hwnd;
        MSG Msg;

        hwnd = FindWindowW(NULL, L"Sublime Text");

        while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
        {
            TranslateMessage(&Msg);
            DispatchMessage(&Msg);
        }
        return Msg.wParam;
```

Comment: Windows doesn't work like that.

Comment: Why? I can find some window, get hwnd and get message from it. Or not?

Comment: Since other windows locate in other thread? And If I want to get some message from window, I'll need to use SendMessage from somewhere?

Comment: You cannot get messages from another window that is not part of the same process. It doesn't work like that at all. *Why* is because that's how the Windows OS works. (BTW, you're not even checking to see if FindWindow() succeeded before using the hwnd. Always check the return value of API calls to see if they succeeded. **Always**. No exception.)

Comment: Also, your code is clearly not C++. They're not the same language. Please only use tags that actually apply to your post.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a hook. But before you go on you would do well to revise how windows and messaging works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the thread that creates a window can directly receive and dispatch messages for that window.  `GetMessage()` retrieves messages from the calling thread's message queue, so it can only be used with windows that are owned by the calling thread.

Since you are trying to catch messages for a window that is not yours, you will have to use [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) or [`SetWinEventHook()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) to install a hook callback into that window's owning thread, and then that callback can intercept the desired messages/events for that window.  You can use [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid) to get the IDs of the Process and Thread that own the window.

If you use `SetWindowsHookEx()` and are trying to hook a window in another process, your callback must reside in a DLL so it can be injected into that process.  You do not need to do that with `SetWinEventHook()`.